# Lookups are empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column

I have a rule set with two content types A and B.

Both content types have the same parent content type and nothing else more. They are identical except for their name and ID.

I'm adding files to the this rule set with `SPFileCollection.Add(string, byte[], Hashtable)`

If I add an item with content type A the lookup is working fine. If I add an item with content type B the code runs fine and I get an exception in ULS:

```
 Stack trace:   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Hashtable properties, Boolean overwrite)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Hashtable properties)
```

Multilookups are working fine. User and Multi user fields too. It's only lookups that don't work.

Anybody have any clue/idea what's going on?

This is all I get in uls

```
03-24-2015 07:44:30.19  w3wp.exe (0x0870)   0x5394  SharePoint Foundation   Dev Events  ajbpn   Medium  Set EventFiringDisabled to [False].  Stack trace: [   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.HandleEventCallback[ReceiverType,PropertiesType](Object callbackData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadPool.WaitCallbackWrapper(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  ]    bcc7f59c-66c4-501b-1040-4211a15703bc

03-24-2015 07:44:30.22  w3wp.exe (0x0870)   0x4358  SharePoint Foundation   Dev Events  ajbpn   Medium  Set EventFiringDisabled to [False].  Stack trace: [   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.HandleEventCallback[ReceiverType,PropertiesType](Object callbackData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadPool.WaitCallbackWrapper(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  ]    c4c7f59c-e628-501b-1040-479915665091

03-24-2015 07:44:30.22  w3wp.exe (0x0870)   0x4B9C  SharePoint Foundation   General 90hv    Unexpected  b1c39df8-f7b0-4003-942a-2922bbd84bea Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Hashtable properties, Boolean overwrite)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Hashtable properties)    ...
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I added the most relevant parts of ULS logs. It's just a guid with a stacktrace. I'll check ULS and see if I'm missing something. I also had an ItemAdded and ItemUpdated even receivers but disabled them and the issue persisted.

Comment: Sounds there's an event receiver on that list doing something with ContentType B.